# PHP assoc array to MySQL table, creating a column for each key?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on some reusable code, basically. My idea is that I'd like to create an array based on a row in a database, where each column is the array's keys. The program then modifies the array, adding new keys if they weren't already in the database, and at the end of the program, the new array data is put back into the database, adding any new columns if they didn't exist first. Thus when making a new program with this reusable code, you don't have to mess with creating all the database columns.

I'm just looking for it to be an array, not some complex object. Kinda like the same way you would use $_SESSION or such. The database wouldn't change frequently, I'm only suggesting that the tables are created when the new program first runs, then don't change (so long as the programmer knows what he's doing). The array would be used securely; you wouldn't put user input into a $_SESSION key, would you?

So, a few questions.

Firstly, is this even a good idea?

Second, are there any similar stand-alone solutions already available which I can use or reference?

Finally, is there anything I should know about how to go about doing it if I need to from scratch?

Thank you a lot for any opinions or knowledge on this technique.

Comment: This sounds an aweful lot like building the db with PHPMyAdmin. What is different about it? The programmer still has to configure it and specify what he/she wants. So it really sounds like you just want to do what PHPMyAdmin does, but with the config in an array instead of with SQL commands or a gui to walk you through it. Seems like your almost reinventing the wheel here. Why can't they just use a db GUI for this part?

Comment: One reason is that, when developing, the speed that you can test iterations is important. If, in your dev environment, you want to change the database columns frequently when trying different things out, it would be so much faster than getting into PHPMyAdmin every five minutes to change the db. This would pollute your db, but you just start with a fresh one when you go into production. It means less configuration, less to think about, but the end result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the programmer knows what columns he is going to use ahead of time, then he should just create the table. If the programmer *doesn't* know what the fields are called (they're determined by external forces like users, web service calls, etc), then you are opening yourself up for a major world of hurt as you have basically just passed all validation of data integrity to an outside source.

Outside sources are completely beyond your control and can do such lovely things as send bad data, especially if they happen to be users, or things operated by users, or things built by humans, or... well... anything else..

The rest of what you're talking about (select from a DB, modify returned value, save result) can be accomplished with things called Object-Relational-Maps. I can think of two good, standalone ORM systems in PHP: [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) and [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/).

Comment: It's an abstraction layer between the program and the database, so the programmer doesn't have to alter the database at all, it just happens automatically, and can have other columns already in it from the reusable part of the code he doesn't need to work with. No outside sources. I've already looked into ORMs, but I'm just looking for something as simple as possible.

Comment: Symfony's YAML syntax allows for schema definitions, your better bet is to look into that. But even if you choose something else, your best bet is to have something which defines the schema up front.

Answer (score 0):

Database structures shouldn't change frequently, which is what it sounds like your solution is intended to do. Usually creating any given table is just a single query once, with the occasional 'alter' as business needs change over time. Allowing for random mutability at the drop of a hat sounds like it'd be a nightmare to support.

Even if you did make it easy to add/alter/remove tables like this, there's still all the associated overhead of actually USING the new fields, removing deleted fields from existing code, yada yada yada.

Comment: Nope, the columns are created the first time the new program runs, then don't change. As long as the programmer knows what he's doing and doesn't do anything weird or insecure.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that traditional database tables shouldn't change like that. I'd suggest that you'd take a look at document databases like MongoDB, you can save array to the database as it is and you don't need to worry about the changing structure.

Comment: The database won't change on-the-fly, just once ever, unless the program is modified. Then the tables can be queried and such, unlike if I used serialize() on the array and just stuck it in one column.

Comment: Still you'd be better off having hard-coded migration scripts to run in case the program needs DB changes. When doing proper db design you'll also need to take care of indexes etc.

Comment: Mongo definitely came to mind when I read the description. But after I realized that this is only for building the initial db it kinda went to the back burner (no offense to Mongo).

Comment: @pthurmond: Yep, no need for Mongo in this case. Having spent months trying to create a working EAV database on top of MySQL, I found Mongo to be a gift from heaven. :D